# Should it be Illegal to alter Someones Memories?

Tags: law-enforcement, cybernetics, mind-control

This is the next part of my Direct Neural Link tech series
(Original question here [The legality of Direct Neural Link Technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180764/the-legality-of-direct-neural-link-technology?noredirect=1#)) the previous question was about how to prevent someone from hijacking someone’s cybernetic implants to commit murder.  This time the question is about something deeper and darker.  Memory alteration.

We see this all the time in speculative fiction, deleting short-term memories, implanting fake memories, copying and storing memories, wipe memories clean even complete personality re-writes.

Now the benefits this tech provides, such as helping those with PTSD, or reforming criminals are barely talked about and I think that is because this application of DNL tech has the most potential for abuse.  After all, memory is arguably what makes us who we are, we need our memories in order to make decisions in our daily lives, we make mistakes and learn from them.  So if the technology exists where memories could be altered or even outright erased, what safeguards can put in place?  If the government-controlled it what’s to stop them from using it as a punishment for criminals?  What’s to stop some street gangs from getting their hands on the tech and using it to make willing slaves?  What if instead of just killing a witness to a crime, you just erase the memory of it ever happening?  Or make it so they can’t go to the police because the witness was implanted with the memory of them commuting the murder?

This tech may lead to a world where the classical assurance, “I think therefore I am,” is answered with the disturbing question, “how are you so sure they’re your thoughts?”  And I think I am not alone in the fears of this application of the tech because a video game was made showing that this tech is nothing short of dangerous, which ironically given its name and subject matter, was forgotten (check this trailer out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk_rsCZxgyM)  Personally I think that while DNL tech might be welcomed, this application is better off theoretical and maybe even illegal.

So here is the question: **Would the threats of Memory alteration be enough to outlaw the tech that would make it possible?**

Comment: Human memory is very fluid and always changing. One does not need science-fiction technology to change it; see for example the well-known phenomenon of [false memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory), or the notorious unreliability of eye witnesses. And, moreover, every time you tell a story you alter someone's memories; every time you speak with somebody you alter their memories; every time you ask a question you alter someone's memories.

Comment: Ah, and *cogito* is best translated **I am thinking**. It's about a momentary action: I am sure that I exist *now* when I am thinking.

Comment: @AlexP That “how are you so sure they’re your thoughts?” Line was taken from the SFDebris review of Dark City (https://sfdebris.com/videos/films/darkcity.php) which I found appropriate because it’s about an alien experiment on a city where everyone’s memories are altered and personalities rewritten every single night.

Comment: Here is a simple legal parallel to start you off - lies. There are some that are illegal, for example fraud. That's not *exactly* altering memory but it may as well be for practical effect - you've made somebody believe something that isn't based in reality. Simple everyday lies like "good day" and similar aren't really prosecuted, though. You have to find where the line is for your world. Normally "lies" have to actually be accompanied with some harm to be illegal. One could very well argue that memory alteration is always harming an individual.

Comment: Will someone whose memories have been altered know *that* their memories have been altered?

Comment: @Vivelin it's not impossible. At the very least [you want to avoid these situations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yd4iGKTMlTU) if you give consent to a specific memory being erased. However, even if a person is not aware after the memory alteration, they can certainly find out later. With that said, I'm not sure if knowledge of memory alteration is relevant for its legality. Usually whether or not something is illegal doesn't depend on whether it's know. With my previous example: fraud. Even if you don't know you're a victim of fraud, the fraudster themselves is still guilty.

Comment: There was a short story that dealt with this concept. A doctor accidentally killed a patient because he gave her the wrong medicine for her condition (there were two conditions with similar symptoms, but one was very rare). The doctor's guilt was consuming him, so he had his memory erased. He felt better, until he did it again. At the end of the story, the technician doing the erasure was talking to somebody else, remarked that this doctor was on his third erasure. The moral is that erasing painful memories may prevent learning from mistakes.

Comment: "I think therefore I am" does not rely on memory, simply on having the experience of thinking. Subjective experience requires a self to experience it.

Comment: The real dystopian future is when it becomes illegal NOT to have certain memories/ideas deleted.  "You were the victim of a crime?  And you want to remember it?  Why?  That isn't allowed!"

Comment: @Jedediah I acknowledged that handling PTSD was the more positive uses, but even if that was a clear cut that application should totally be legal for moral reasons, how do you keep out of the memory wipe loop?  (Where you erase A memory, forget it, learn you memory was wiped, learn the awful truth you wanted so badly to forget, wiped it again and round she goes).  Not to mention that consent forms could be faked, and video of you pooring your heart out can be forged, and once your memory is gone, how can you be so sure what a stranger says happened is the truth?

Comment: How would DNL alter the memory of a person on a cell connection level? With brain-computer interface (BCI) you can't (directly) alter the mind. You create alternative pathways. For instance after a trauma a patient may have speak recognition problems. Creating alternative pathways would help him overcome this condition. The user will also have an extra memory to store the info required to the Interface, a resident AI that manages the users requests and provides connection to the network. You can change THAT memory but the user would clearly be aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very difficult question to answer. Personally, I'm of the belief that the whole field of 'mind magic' inherently aligns itself with "evil", especially since its most powerful applications can easily manipulate someone's free will, ability to consent, and identity even as a side-effect.

It's widely accepted that memories make us who we are and steer decision-making. Let me give a hypothetical example:

> I want to remove my memories of a war experience where I killed
> multiple enemy combatants with a knife. Occasionally, I wake up with
> cold sweats from the nightmares of that moment. Sometimes, when I'm
> washing my hands it feels like the blood just won't wash off. I
> figure, my life would be better off if I didn't remember that terrible
> day, and all the nightmares it's spawned since.
>
> I consult with some doctors, talk it over with my friends and family,
> and finally go to the psychosurgeon. There, we review the memories I'd
> like to get rid of, and after being witnessed and recorded I sign
> notarized papers. Then the memories are removed.
>
> After the procedure, I feel different. I feel great. I look back, and
> wonder what was so terrible that it was keeping me down all the time.
> This gets me curious. What did I miss? I know it was apparently
> terrible enough for me to get it removed, but how bad could it be?
> I've watched plenty of graphic movies, I'm not scared of gore. I watch
> the video I made for myself before I went into the procedure, and I'm
> confused. I say I killed multiple people with a knife. Who is this person? I don't recognize them, even though
> they're apparently me.
>
> Months, maybe years pass, and all the while this nagging part of my brain won't shut up. I know that there's a part of me; a part of my experience that I gave up. What was it? Am I still the same person? If I had the memories back, would I do it again?

In this example, the person is different than they were before. Removing the memory, even though it was terrible and they wanted it gone, changed the personality, identity, and worldview.

---

All that said, to actually answer your question, memory manipulation is too useful a technology to pass up. People developed the atomic bomb among all sorts of potentially horrendous technologies, despite extreme push back. History has shown time and time again that fighting technological progress is futile in the long run.

Comment: It's no surprise. If you deny technology to yourself, that doesn't mean that the rest of the world will do the same. That's simply disadvantaging yourself for nothing. That's why "hero destroys evil prototype and everyone lives happily every after" endings are so cheesy and stupid to me in books/movies/whatever.

Answer (score 5):

As with so many things, the line is likely to be drawn at consent.  Altering someone's memories with their consent is likely to be legal, outside of perhaps a few areas which are not allowed to be removed.  (Although it's surely not the best example, the first to mind is that erasing someone's memory of time in prison or other legal penalties would likely be prohibited.)  Altering someone's memories without their consent would almost certainly be unconditionally illegal, except perhaps as part of a court-ordered legal punishment, such as in the Babylon 5 episode in which a serial killer is sentenced to "Death of Personality" and mindwiped.

Aside from legality, there is also the question of accessibility.  I would be *extremely* surprised if memory alteration were to be a quick and easy process that just anyone could do if given five minutes of free time with the subject.  It would more likely be a rather involved process, requiring a highly-educated specialist to perform, much like surgery is in the real world today, placing outside the reach of most people who might use it unscrupulously.

Comment: "[...] erasing someone's memory of time in prison [...]" - why would such a society *have* prisons? That sentence feels like using your universal fabricator to make a screwdriver.

Comment: What about opting to have your memory of witnessing a crime wiped, because you like the criminal and you don't want to be able to testify against them, nor want to be accused of perjury?  If this is illegal, would it even be recognizable that a person had witnessed a crime?  If not, it seems unenforceable.

Comment: @RutherRendommeleigh - As I said in the answer, it was "surely not the best example". However, just because you have the capability to alter memories, that does not mean it will be used as a one-size-fits-all solution to penalizing crime. Among other things, editing _memory_ does not necessarily imply editing _personality_ - you may not be able to just wave a DNL wand at a criminal and transform them into a law-abiding citizen, thus forcing you to work with the same kinds of penalties currently available.

Answer (score 4):

Technology with use and abuse potential will be **regulated**. It will first be used in cutting-edge labs, perhaps supervised by university ethics committees. Next, prototype clinical trials, perhaps as laws rather than one-off decisions. By the time it reaches the criminal market, the industry will be established.

- Imagine some trauma victim who gets counseling and then has the traumatic memories removed in a clinical setting.
- Imagine an intelligence agent who volunteered before the mission that the memories will be removed in a safe house during debriefing.
- Imagine a student who opts to have artificial memories of intensive learning implanted, overwriting the less interesting parts of the spring break.

Once those uses are common, rolling back will be quite difficult.

Comment: One very interesting situation that just occurred to me is if the memory alteration is definitely not negative but the overall process against a law or policy. For example, somebody was made to go through a corrective course. As a silly example, say they were violating the company dress policy and had to go to Windsor necktie knot course. For whatever valid reason, they want these memories deleted now - the course is related to bad and harmful memories. However, if that corrective course was formally mandated for them to keep the job. The regulation around this would be interesting.

Comment: @VLAZ, in most jurisdictions the job-related course would be a *civil* matter. Memory altering would be a *human rights* matter. So the person could have the dress code course deleted, but he may be required *by terms of contract* to inform the employer, and get fired. Depending on the labor rights standards.

Comment: I was trying to make a light-hearted example as a stand in for heavier themed ones. You could be in the same situation after getting in trouble with the law.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of those "every answer is valid" questions.

Should it be illegal to shot people for trespassing?
Should it be illegal to stone women for being unfaithful?
Should it be illegal to cut arms form stealing?
Should it be illegal for people of "frowned upon" sexuality be castrated?
Should it be illegal to perform euthanasia at willing patient?
<... insert thousands more examples here ...>

Each of those is legal in some societies that think that benefits outweigh disadvantages and illegal in others. Also even when some of those is unconditionally legal/illegal in one place, in another it would require a specific set of circumstances to be legal or illegal.

Just like those, memory altering will be illegal in some societies depending on **circumstances of each case** and **previously formed cultural factors** and legal in others. There are no definite answer "yes, it should" or "no, it should not" for every case.

Answer (score 2):

Carrying out any medical procedure on someone without their consent is going to be illegal.

The only question is how serious an offence it is compared to causing physical injury.

Comment: Hehe, tell it to people undergoing forcible chemical castration. Yes, it is pretty much alive in this very decade EU (Moldova), South Korea, USA (Iowa. Louisiana, Alabama, etc) and some other "1st world" locations. Or if you wish example where "without consent" would inhibit positive action, see many examples of cultist parents brainwashing their children (or simply cultist environment brainwashing their adherents) to deny life-saving treatment.